# How to return piplined reseult and use dynamic cursor on dynamic table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would create a dynamic table and use my cursor on this table and return a pipelined result to select the result but I have a problem. 
He does not recognize my new table

It worked if I create a table before execute the function in the package and if I don't execute immediate my created table, but I do not want a permanent table, only a temporary table.

Where is my problem?

Press CTRL+F and search --Now He don't know info_table so what am I suppose to do?

----So this is in my header package

```
    type data_rec is record 
      ( 
       l_util_id_source      number,  
       l_util_id_cible  number,  
       l_level         number
     ) ; 


type l_data_type is table of data_rec;

function obtenir_closeness return l_data_type pipelined ;


--And now my body

function obtenir_closeness return l_data_type pipelined 
     is 
     PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

    cc sys_refcursor;
    l_row lig_relation%ROWTYPE;
    sorti_type  data_rec; 

V_STRING VARCHAR2(1000) := 'DECLARE
    sorti_type  data_rec;
    BEGIN

  FOR C1 IN (SELECT * FROM info_table) LOOP
    null;

  END LOOP;

END;';

begin

test3();
test4();
```

--Create my table work.

```
execute immediate 'create table info_table (util_id_source varchar2(50),
util_id_cible varchar2(50),
level_connaissance number )';
commit;
```

--Insert in my table work.

```
execute immediate 'insert into info_table select util_id_source,util_id_cible,1
from lig_relation
group by util_id_source,util_id_cible';
commit;
```

--Now He dont know info_table so what i am suppose to do?

```
 OPEN cc for 'select * from info_table';

     LOOP 
        FETCH cc INTO l_row; 

               EXIT WHEN CC%NOTFOUND; 
                        sorti_type.l_util_id_source := l_row.util_id_source; 
                        sorti_type.l_util_id_cible := l_row .util_id_cible; 
                        sorti_type.l_level := l_row .level_connaissance; 

  pipe row(sorti_type);
END LOOP;

  CLOSE cc; 
  test5(); 
 return; 

end obtenir_closeness ;
```

--This is procedure 3

```
procedure test3
    is
    v_ctr number:=1;
    v_execute_1 varchar2(32767);

    begin
    --This is where i insert what i need and it work.
v_execute_1:= 'begin 
while :v_ctr<10
loop
FOR l_info IN(
select * from info_table where level_connaissance = :v_ctr)
loop
insert into info_table select l_info.util_id_source,util_id_cible,:v_ctr+1
from lig_relation
where util_id_source = l_info.util_id_cible
and (select count(*) from info_table where util_id_source = l_info.util_id_source  and util_id_cible = lig_relation.util_id_cible)=0
group by util_id_source,util_id_cible;
end loop;

:v_ctr := :v_ctr+1;
end loop;
end;';

execute immediate v_execute_1 using in out v_ctr;
commit;
    end test3;
```

--This is procedure 5

```
procedure test5
    is
 Pragma Autonomous_transaction;
    begin
    execute immediate 'drop table info_table';
    commit;
    end test5;



END
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, don't do it this way. In Oracle, we *usually* - but you can read it as *never* - create tables dynamically. This is what MS SQL Server does.

As you don't want to use a permanent table, then create a **global temporary table** (GTT) (or a private one, if your Oracle version supports it). For example:

```
SQL> create global temporary table info_table
  2    (util_id_source        varchar2(50),
  3     util_id_cible         varchar2(50),
  4     level_connaissance    number
  5    )
  6    on commit preserve rows;            --> or ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS; pick one

Table created.

SQL>
```

Data you put into that table will be visible only to you, and only during session (if you choose to preserve rows on commit) or transaction (if you choose to delete them). Once you quit the session, data will be lost, the table will be empty, it won't occupy any space. So, if that was your concern, I suggest you switch to a GTT.

Note that you create the table only once, and use it as many times as you want. Do **NOT** drop it (especially not from your PL/SQL procedures) and create on-the-fly. Think of it as if it was a *normal* table.

Now, as you have the table, you don't have to do anything dynamically (which doesn't scale, is difficult to maintain, you can't spot an error easily ... avoid it if you can). Reading your code, I'd say that you can do that. Also, you'll avoid a problem you currently have (the table doesn't exist, yet).

The final remark: procedure `test5` doesn't have to be `autonomous`, and you don't have to `commit` after `drop` because `DROP` is DDL, it'll implicitly commit before and after executing the command. Though, as you won't be needing that procedure any more, it is irrelevant in this context, but keep it on mind.